# Determine the radius of convergence of the series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series

I'm trying to solve an exercise in the Complex Analysis textbook, but I can't use the hint given by the author. Here is the exercise:

Determine the radius of convergence of the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} z^{n}$ when $a_{n} =\frac{( n!)^{3}}{( 3n) !}$.

Hint: Use Stirling’s formula, which says that $n!\sim \ cn^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-n}$  for some $c >0$.

I figured it out using the ratio test, but the answer here should be using the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem with $\limsup$ because I couldn't find a discussion of the ratio test before the exercise.

Textbook is by Stein and Shakarchi, Chapter $1$, exercise $16$.

**Edited:**

I think I solved this problem by trying another form of the Stirling formula from the internet, but is it correct?

$$
Γ( x) \sim  x^{x -1} e^{- x}\sqrt{2\pi x}
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{( n!)^{3}}{( 3n) !} &\sim \frac{\left(n^{n -1} e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\right)^{3}}{( 3n)^{( 3n) -1} e^{-( 3n)}\sqrt{2\pi ( 3n)}}\\
\\
&=\frac{n^{3n -3} e^{- 3n}\sqrt{2\pi n}^{3}}{( 3n)^{( 3n) -1} e^{-( 3n)}\sqrt{2\pi ( 3n)}}\\
\\
&=\frac{n^{3n -1} n^{2}\sqrt{2\pi  n}^{3}}{( 3n)^{( 3n) -1}\sqrt{2\pi ( 3n)}}\\
\\
&=\frac{ n^{3n -1} n^{2}( 2\pi n)}{( 3n)^{( 3n) -1} 3^{1/2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{n^{3} 2\pi }{3^{( 3n) -1} 3^{1/2}}
\end{align*}
Then
$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(\frac{n^{3} 2\pi }{3^{( 3n) -3/2}}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{3^{3}}
$$

Comment: Try using the Hint.

Comment: If $n!=cF(n)n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}$ and $(3n)!=cF(3n)(3n)^{3n+1/2}e^{-3n}$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}F(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}F(3n)=1$ then what happens to ($1/|a_n|)^{1/n}$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: The ratio test is the simplest way. Moreover the ratio test implies the root test: $\lim{a_{n+1}\over a_n}=a \implies \lim a_n^{1/n}=a.$ Applying Stirling's formula is an overkill in my opinion

Comment: I suspect that any textbook on Complex Analysis assumes its readers are familiar with the ratio test, so there's no need for it to be in the book, and you should feel free to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anything like this involving factorials,
I always use the
n-th root test combined with
$\dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}
\approx \dfrac1{e}$
in the form
$(n!)^{1/n} \approx \dfrac{n}{e}
$.

In this case I get

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\dfrac{( n!)^{3}}{( 3n) !}\right)^{1/n}
&=\dfrac{( n!)^{3/n}}{(( 3n)!)^{1/n}}\\
&=\dfrac{((n!)^{1/n})^3}{((( 3n)!)^{1/(3n)})^3}\\
&\approx\dfrac{(n/e)^3}{(3n/e)^3}\\
&=\dfrac{(n/e)^3}{(3n/e)^3}\\
&=\dfrac1{27}\\
\end{array}
$

which agrees with the proposer's answer.

More generally, this gives

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\dfrac{( n!)^{m}}{( mn) !}\right)^{1/n}
&=\dfrac{( n!)^{m/n}}{(( mn)!)^{1/n}}\\
&=\dfrac{((n!)^{1/n})^m}{((( mn)!)^{1/(mn)})^m}\\
&\approx\dfrac{(n/e)^m}{(mn/e)^m}\\
&=\dfrac{(n/e)^m}{(mn/e)^m}\\
&=\dfrac1{m^m}\\
\end{array}
$